# Selenium - automating javascript button click

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

[Test page](http://www.indeed.ca/cmp/Belwood-Poultry-Ltd./jobs/General-Labourer-41a34df8c87843f8?sjdu=vQIlM60yK_PwYat7ToXhk0ht1loLTVg3_Mbro-8i_Oq8QnPfsih5TP4MoBFYzPbENZnyl4Z8fkU7srETrjh8IA)

I'm using the above `Indeed` page as a test page for selenium. I want to automate clicking the 'apply' button so the form comes up using the Firefox webdriver. I have the following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.indeed.ca/cmp/Belwood-Poultry-Ltd./jobs/General-Labourer-41a34df8c87843f8?sjdu=vQIlM60yK_PwYat7ToXhk0ht1loLTVg3_Mbro-8i_Oq8QnPfsih5TP4MoBFYzPbENZnyl4Z8fkU7srETrjh8IA')
self.mouse = webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver)  
driver.find_element_by_class_name("indeed-apply").click()
```

There's no error generated but the apply button isn't clicked (nothing appears to happen). Obviously that HTML tag isn't the one attached to the javascript event that triggers the click and I'm not sure how to fix this.

Thank you

Comment: I don't see the button when I open the link. Check the source of the file and if the `<a>` tag is used for the button then try using [`find_element_by_link_text`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text). If `<button>` tag has been used then try [`find_element_by_tag_name`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-tag-name).

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, the class name is not `indeed-apply`, but `indeed-apply-button`:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("indeed-apply-button").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two **Apply Now** button so if you want to click the first one see below:

`driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".indeed-apply-button")[0].click()`